# Private conversion function results in "ambiguous default type conversion" error (c++)

Tags: c++, g++, type-conversion

First, a tiny example that demonstrates the problem:

```
struct Bar {
    enum Baz {aa, bb, cc};
    Baz baz_;

    operator Baz() const { return baz_; }
    private:
        template<typename T> operator T() const;
};

int main() {
    Bar bar;
    switch (bar) {
        case Bar::aa:
            break;
        case Bar::bb:
            break;
        case Bar::cc:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code with g++ 4.7.0 gives the following error:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:12:16: error: ambiguous default type conversion from ‘Bar’
foo.cpp:12:16: error:   candidate conversions include ‘template<class T> Bar::operator T() const’
```

My understanding is that, since the struct object is being "switched" on, the compiler will try to find a conversion function to an integral or enum type. I explicitly provide a public conversion function to the Bar::Baz enum type and would like it to use that.

The confusing part to me is that the compiler also finds the *private* conversion function and then cannot decide which to use. Why is it even considering the private function? If I add an explicit cast, say `switch((int)bar)`, then *only* the private conversion function matches and the compiler rightly complains that it cannot use it since it's private. So, since the private conversion function can't be used in this context, why isn't the choice between the two unambiguous?

Interestingly, I believe (though I'm not 100% sure) this code compiles without error on g++ 4.6.

**edit:** As pointed out by James McNellis in the comments, the fact that the private conversion function is templated is also relevant here.

Comment: Don't use implicit conversions and you'll be much happier.

Comment: The private doesn't come into the overload resolution.

Comment: Clang, Comeau, and Visual C++ all accept the program as-is.  The specification of `switch` states that there must exist "a single non-explicit conversion function to integral or enumeration type."  This could, perhaps, be read as limiting the overload resolution.  The question therefore is:  does the "all other things being equal, nontemplates are preferable to templates" rule apply?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus That may be good advice, but I ran into this situation in an existing codebase and wanted to understand the behavior.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Is the "nontemplates are preferable to templates" rule documented in the standard somewhere? I just read section 13.3.1 par. 7, which basically says that candidate functions generated from function templates are not treated specially in overload resolution (so g++ 4.7 appears to be correct).

Comment: C++11 §13.3.3/1 has a paragraph that starts "Given these definitions..."  The third bullet point under that paragraph is the "all other things being equal, nontemplates are preferable to templates" rule.

Comment: Thanks...that does seem relevant. C++ is one complex beast :).

Comment: @DrewFrank I think you have cornered yourself with this flawed usage of switch and template usage, then finding it as a complex beast. Nobody on earth would `switch` a struct which has a template overload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access control comes *after* overload resolution. This is specified in the standard, §13.3

> Overload resolution is a mechanism for selecting the best function to call given a list of expressions that are
>   to be the arguments of the call and a set of candidate functions that can be called based on the context of the
>   call. The selection criteria for the best function are the number of arguments, how well the arguments
>   match the types of the parameters of the candidate function, how well (for nonstatic member functions) the
>   object matches the implied object parameter, and certain other properties of the candidate function. [Note:
>   the function selected by overload resolution is not guaranteed to be appropriate for the context. Other
>   restrictions, such as the accessibility of the function, can make its use in the calling context ill-formed. ]

So the overload resolution can chose a function that is not appropriate for the given context.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it right up. It seems strange that it would compile with g++ 4.6, but if it does I guess it's in violation of the standard.

Comment: @DrewFrank it is an interesting question. I had never seen it with switch and templates, so to be honest right now I cannot say for sure which of the two behaviours is standard compliant.

Comment: Would you explain the overload resolution behavior in this case?  That is, given the specification of `switch` and the "all other things being equal, nontemplates are preferable to templates" rule, why is there an ambiguity?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis the more I look at it, the more I'm convinced my analysis is wrong.

Comment: juanchopanza: I'm leaning that way, too. Everything in your answer is clearly correct, but the situation I presented is more subtle than that due to the templated function. If you or @JamesMcNellis edit/create an answer that incorporates that aspect of things, I will "accept" that answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
switch(expression)
```

The expression must be of an integral type or of a class type for which there is an unambiguous conversion to integral type.